How do I lay and attach additional layers of plywood underlayment over an uneven subfloor when installing LVP or "Rigid Core" flooring?
I have a small room that I want to install floating LVP or "Rigid Core" flooring tiles. I need to raise the floor to match the height of an adjacent room that also has LVP flooring. I have a pretty unlevel subfloor with plywood subfloor installed "between" the joists. I figured the layers needed above the subfloor to be...
#1. A sheet of 3/4 inch plywood,
#2. A sheet of 1/4 inch plywood,
#3. Cork underlayment, and
#4. the tile.
How do I prepare the subfloor, and how do I lay then attach the layers of plywood over it?
The adjacent room is actually the hallway with LVP tile in a wood grain that goes throughout our house. We are adding a solid color, solid core, flooring to our bathroom, got it for cheap. The bathroom had a very thick mortar bed with metal mesh over the subfloor under ceramic tile, that I took up. When I installed the LVP in the hallway and throughout the rest of the house it was easiest just to lay it on top of the existing vinyl, in some parts. Anyway, yes, the plywood subfloor is recessed between the joists, not laid on top of the joists. You can actually see the top of each joist. The subfloor is not flat, it has raised areas and recessed areas. It is level, I guess I misspoke.

What is in the adjacent room that you need to raise the floor 1 and 1/4 inches?   Also solid core flooring needs a surface that is flat not necessarily level.    Finally what doe sit mean the plywood is "between" Joists?

Extra layers of sub flooring usually do not make a floor flat.  Fix the floor unevenness/flatness first, then add extra sheets if needed.

You can pour self-leveling compound to make a flat & level base. It's less work, but the material is costly. For a small room, that may not be a major issue. From there you can add your  plywood and other layers as desired. Be sure to plug/seal any holes in the floor first.
If the joist spacing is reasonable and the tops of the joists are flat, you can remove anything raised above them and fasten the new plywood to the joists, ignoring whatever is lower than the joists. If the tops of the joists are NOT flat, the method above or the one below can be applied.
You can scribe shims (cut to make each point shimmed the same level) to make a flat & level base for your plywood equal to the highest projection above the tops of the joists. It's a lot of fiddly work.
